# Usage of Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent

Tags: vb.net, xaml

I'm trying to upload a file from a VB.net/XAML app to a webdav server. The code below succeed in creating the file but i don't succeed in transferring the content of the file.

```vb
Public Async Function transferFile(fichier As StorageFile) As Tasks.Task
    Dim url As String = "http://myserverip/remote.php/webdav/"
    Dim userName As String = "user"
    Dim password As String = "password"
    Dim www As Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient = Nothing
    Dim cred As Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential = New Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(url, userName, password)
    Dim filters As Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter = New Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter
    Dim u As Uri = New Uri(url & fichier.Name)

    Dim c As Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent = Nothing


    filters.AllowUI = False
    filters.ServerCredential = cred
    www = New Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filters)

    Await www.PutAsync(u, c)



End Function
```

My goal is to convert a `storagefile` to a `httpStreamContent`, but if I'm wrong and there's another way to do please let me know.
I think I do not have best practices with the `Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent` class, I did not find any sample, if you just have one link or even a sample that would be wonderful. I could be more specific and upload all the project if needed, but I'd rather prefer just a sample in order to succeed almost by myself.

Comment: I did not insist, but all my attemps where at the `Dim c As Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent = Nothing` line, i tried replacing the `nothing` by many things ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to do the "old way" ... if anyone knows better i'm willing to know ;-)

```
    Dim cred As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential(userName, password)
    Dim httpReq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url & fichier.Name)
    Dim data As Byte() = getFileBytes(fichier.Path)
    Dim s As System.IO.Stream = Nothing

    httpReq.Credentials = cred
    httpReq.Method = "PUT"
    httpReq.ContentLength = data.Length
    s = Await httpReq.GetRequestStreamAsync
    s.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    s.Close()
    Dim httpRep As HttpWebResponse = Await httpReq.GetResponseAsync
```

Thanx for reading ;-)

```
Private Function getFileBytes(fichier As String) As Byte()
    Dim s As System.IO.Stream = New System.IO.FileStream(fichier, IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim br As System.IO.BinaryReader = New System.IO.BinaryReader(s)
    Dim result As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(s.Length))
    s.Close()
    Return result
End Function
```